# Quickly and efficiently rescale displayed image using bicubic filtering

Tags: wxpython, zooming

I'm trying to edit an existing image viewer to quickly zoom in/out of a displayed image. Right now, the image is scaled by using PIL to generate a new copy of the image at the desired size and that new image is displayed. This works fine for the initial display, but causes massive lag when trying to zoom in with the scrollwheel.

I'm not using wx.Image for this - a PILImage is created and drawn to a DC directly using DrawBitmap.

dc.SetUserScale appears to do exactly what I want, except for the resize algorithm. Currently the image is resized using Bicubic resampling. I'm guessing SetUserScale uses nearest neighbor; whatever it is, it causes jagged lines when zooming out on hard lines. I don't see any way to change the filter used.

Is there a way to use bicubic resampling to quickly scale an image? I'm assuming this requires moving away from generating new images on the fly, but if there's a quick way to do that that's also fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to use a [GraphicsContext](https://docs.wxpython.org/wx.GraphicsContext.html) instead of a drawing context and not rescale the image at all. gc.DrawBitmap takes height and width as parameters, and will scale the image to the new size on-demand. SetInterpolationQuality can be used to ensure it uses higher quality resampling (if it's supported - a comment says it might not be). I assume this involves hardware acceleration, as it is much faster than scaling the image in PIL.

The API for GraphicsContext is very similar to DrawingContext, but it is not a drop-in replacement.

Another option is to use [pycairo](https://pycairo.readthedocs.io)/wxcairo to scale the image with a transformation matrix, again to upscale the image on-demand instead of actually creating a larger image in memory. Roughly:

```
    ctx = wxcairo.ContextFromDC(dc)
    imgpat = cairo.SurfacePattern(img)   # img is an existing cairo.ImageSurface
    matrix = cairo.Matrix()
    matrix.scale(_orig_width / width, _orig_height / height)
    imgpat.set_matrix(matrix)
    ctx.set_source(imgpat)
    ctx.paint() #Draws to the DC
```

Which may just be what the graphics context is doing in the background.